# Plot log-normal distribution in R

Tags: r, lognormal-distribution

I need to plot lognormal distribution with mean 1 and variance 0.6 in `R`. 
I tried to do this using `rlnorm` function in `R` as

```
x= rlnorm(500, log(1), log(0.6))

plot(density(x))
```

`log(0.6)` is negative that might be the reason my code is not working but the `R` documentation for `lnorm` says the value for standard deviation is given in log. Correct me if I have understood it incorrectly. Can someone please give me correct `R` code?

Comment: This sounds like straight coursework. Can you explain the context in which it arises please? The parameters you supply to rlnorm are NOT the log of the mean and variance of the lognormal (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) for an explanation of the usual parameterization), but in any case, to plot a density, you just use `dlnorm` rather than generate  a random sample and smooth it.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. This is not a coursework or something. This question comes from the survival analysis study I am involved. I wanted to compare distributions of gamma frailty and lognormal frailty. I was not clear on the use of `meanlog` and `sdlog` part in `lnorm` function. Thanks!!

Answer (score 16):

As @ocram stated, the parameters `meanlog` and `sdlog` correspond to $\mu$ and $\sqrt{\theta}$ so you do not need to take the log yourself when specifiying the mean and standard deviation of the distribution.  Here is some revised code with the true density function plotted (without having to sample as @Glen_b above suggested) and the density estimate.

```
x = rlnorm(500,1,.6)
grid = seq(0,25,.1)

plot(grid,dlnorm(grid,1,.6),type="l",xlab="x",ylab="f(x)")
lines(density(x),col="red")

legend("topright",c("True Density","Estimate"),lty=1,col=1:2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If $X \sim \text{N}(\mu, \theta)$ and $Y = \exp(X)$, then
$$
\text{E}(X) = \mu, \quad \text{Var}(X) = \theta
$$
and
$$
\text{E}(Y) = \exp(\mu + \tfrac{\theta}{2}), \quad \text{Var}(Y) = (\exp(\theta) - 1) \exp(2 \mu + \theta)
$$
In `dlnorm`, the paramaters `meanlog` and `sdlog` correspond to $\mu$ and $\sqrt{\theta}$.