# Sum of dependant log-normal distributions with large uncertainties

Tags: r, covariance, lognormal-distribution

I need to sum many lognormal distributions, which are correlated among them. My distributions simulate vary uncertain gas emissions.

I know their mean value, the percentage uncertainty (defining the 95% CI) and that they are log-normally distributed. For example if I had only two emissions:

Emi1 = 12 with uncertainty of 90%;

Emi2 = 20 with uncertainty of 120%.

I would do:

```
Emi1 <- rlnorm(10000, meanlog=12, sdlog=12*0.9)
Emi2 <- rlnorm(10000, meanlog=20, sdlog=20*1.2)
```

would that be right?

Now I build the covariance matrix following the definition:

```
Emi <- cbind(Emi1, Emi2)
M_mean <- matrix(data=1, nrow=10000) %*% c(12,20)
D <- Emi - M_mean # offset the mean
C <- (nrow(Emi)-1)^-1 *t(D) %*% D # C is the covariance matrix
```

To account for their covariance:

```
Emi_sum_prep <- rlmvnorm (n=10000, mu=c(12,20), Sigma= C) # rlmvnorm from package ‘dmutate’.
```

So far I get stuck at `Emi_sum_prep`. Due to the very large uncertainty, I got plenty of `Inf` in my output. **Any idea how to fix this?**

If I were able to calculate `Emi_sum_prep` then, to calculate the sum of two emissions with dependent uncertainty, I would do:

```
sum    <- rowSums(Emi_sum_prep)
```

and the final distribution:

```
quantile(sum, probs=c(0, 0.05, 0.95, 0.5))
```

**Any suggestion or alternative methods?**

thanks

Comment: If these are 95% CIs, aren't you overestimating the SDs by roughly a factor of 2?

Comment: You pass mean and SD on the log scale. Are you sure the given values are on the log scale (and not on the natural scale)?

Comment: thanks for the replies. @jkm: Even if sd is multiplied by 0.5 I get infinitely large values when using rlmvnorm function. ...and no, I'm not 100% sure, I followed some posts like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68394/plot-log-normal-distribution-in-r